# show data if you have user id - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating a data list and I print it with foreach, i would like it to display the data only if user_id matches the user_id reading the data. (previously I already have the user authentication created)

I want the users who enter to only see the data that contains their user_id.

[image]

I already made the relationship between the users table 'id' field with user_id

**pass the data with:**

```
  public function index()
{
    $servicios = App\Servicio::all();

    return view('home', compact('servicios'));
}
```

How do I show the data that corresponds to the user_id of each one without others seeing their data??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a relationship inside the `User.php` model.

```
public function servicios() {
   return $this->hasMany(Servicio::class);
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $servicios = auth()->user()->servicios;

    return view('home', compact('servicios'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user's list of services easily using `Auth::user()`, example:

`User::with(['servicios'])->find(Auth::id());`

Answer (score 0):

you should get the user from your request, then filter by its id ...

```
  public function index()
{
$user_id=app('request')->user()->id;
    $servicios = App\Servicio::where('user_id',$user_id)->all();
    return view('home', compact('servicios'));
}
```

the user will be present in your request, to make sure of that you should but
the route that use this method in (auth) middleware